# Neovim spellcheck: all the words highlighted as misspelled

Tags: neovim, spell-checking

I've been trying to set up spell checking in neovim.

init.vim:

```
setlocal spell spelllang=ru_ru
```

First time it downloaded `ru.utf-8.spl` and `ru.utf-8.sug`, just as it probably should. Unfortunately, as soon as I try `:set spell/invspell`, all the Russian words get highlighted. What am I missing?

UPD:

English spell checking won't work, too (everything misspelled). The files are here `/usr/share/nvim/runtime/spell/en.utf-8.spl` which looks OK.

UPD:

English spell checking started to work, I am not sure why (I tried `spelllang=ru_ru,en_us`; Russian won't work even as a single option.

Comment: I have simple `set spelllang=ru,en` and it works for me both in vim and nvim for english and russian languages. I toggle it with `set spell` and `set nospell`

Comment: A few seconds ago I tried `:set spelllang=ru_ru` manually, and it works! `init.vim` has `setlocal spell spelllang=ru_ru`. Why `init.vim` does not work properly?

Comment: `set invspell spelllang=ru_ru,en_us` in `init.vim` works reasonably well. All the tabs open on start get checked in English, as well as in Russian. You can toggle it with `:set invspell`. I'd appreciate some explaining before creating an answer.

Comment: It may be because you used `setlocal`; can you try it with `set` to force globally setting the option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set spelllang=ru_ru,en_us
nnoremap 99 :set invspell<CR>
```

This solution is reasonably convenient. A better one is welcome :)